# Ubuntu 16.04 mongo DB installation failing

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

> root@ttpllt23:~# sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org-server Reading
>   package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state
>   information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may
>   mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
>   using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
>   yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
>   information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mongodb-org-server :
>   Depends: libcurl4 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installable E: Unable to
>   correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Hey first solve sudo apt-get update error and then install mongodb-org-server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. For me, the problem was that I was following an install guide in a hurry, failing to see that it was intended for Ubuntu while I myself run Debian. If you are in a similar situation, this should help:

```
apt search dbmongo
```

You should find the following package  :

```
mongodb/stable,now 1:3.2.11-2+deb9u1 amd64 
object/document-oriented database (metapackage)
```

Install it using

```
sudo apt install mongodb
```

If you want a handy GUI, you might also want to install the package "mongodb-compass".